# Solr Not Tokenizing When Indexing

Tags: solr

I'm extremely new to Solr, so I assume I have something very obvious wrong.

I have configured a core to import some fields from a database table called: db.podcast. I am using a DIH to do this. I am taking 4 fields from this table:

```
podcast_id, podcast_desc, podcast_name, podcast_keywords
```

This seems to go smoothly, and the data is added to the index.

However, when I go to inspect the term info in the schema-browser for a field, it seems to have not indexed the field properly. Instead of breaking up all the podcast_desc, say, into the individual words it just gives me the whole description instead.

ie. I was expecting it a list like this:

```
201 A
196 The
185 Then....
```

Instead I get a list like this (i've added the dots to save space:) ) :

```
1 A show on political economy and historical analysis....
  Filling in the gaps left open in the official....
  Carpenter Science Lab Videos...
```

My schema.xml looks like this:

```
<types>
  <fieldtype name='text' class='solr.TextField' >
    <analyzer type="index" >
      <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory" />
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
        ignoreCase="true"
        words="stopwords.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
  </fieldtype>
  <fieldtype name='int' class='solr.TrieIntField' />
</types>

<fields>
    <field name='podcast_id' indexed="true" stored="true" type='int' required="true"/>
    <field name='podcast_name' indexed="true" stored="true" type='text' />
    <field name='podcast_desc' indexed="true" stored="true" type='text' />
    <field name='podcast_keywords' indexed="true" stored="true" type='text' />
</fields>

<uniqueKey>podcast_id</uniqueKey>
```

And my DIH document entity looks like this:

```
<entity name="podcast" query="select podcast_id, podcast_name, podcast_desc, podcast_keywords from db.podcast"
  deltaQuery="select podcast_id from db.podcast where last_modified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
  deltaImportQuery="select podcast_id, podcast_name, podcast_desc, podcast_keywords from db.podcast where podcast_id='dataimporter.delta.podcast_id'">      
</entity>
```

Any ideas whats going wrong? I thought I read somewhere that this would only happen if I was using a 'string' and not a 'text' fieldtype?

**UPDATE 1:**

Here is the logs from the DIH update - it looks like it is not processing any of the documents. Any ideas why this would be happening?

```
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">465</int>
</lst>
<lst name="initArgs">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">podcastDIHconfigfile.xml</str>
    </lst>
</lst>
<str name="command">delta-import</str>
<str name="status">idle</str>
<str name="importResponse"/>
<lst name="statusMessages">
    <str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">22</str>
    <str name="Total Rows Fetched">21</str>
    <str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
    <str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
    <str name="Delta Dump started">2016-01-06 16:14:35</str>
    <str name="Identifying Delta">2016-01-06 16:14:35</str>
    <str name="Deltas Obtained">2016-01-06 16:14:36</str>
    <str name="Building documents">2016-01-06 16:14:36</str>
    <str name="Total Changed Documents">21</str>
    <str name="Time taken">0:0:0.368</str>
</lst>
```

Comment: Where do you inspect the field? In `Field Value (index)` or `Field Value (query)`? Do you see any tokens at all?

Comment: Using the schema Browser, I choose a field and then load the term info - it gives the top terms not as tokens but the full text of the variable. There doesn't seem to be any tokens created.

Comment: You don't use the Schema Browser to check tokens. You use the Analysis page, which should be located at `yourSolrUrl:8983/solr/#/yourCoreName/analysis`. Try checking your search term(s) against the index on the Analysis page. If you see tokens, try checking them as a query on the same page.

Comment: What you are seeing on the Schema Browser is not the actual content of the index, but the raw text. Solr keeps both for different reasons.Should you want to have a look into the index [try luke](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases).

Comment: @TMBT I thought that the schema browser allowed you to see which terms were most common within in the index? I thought you could use it to see what you should put in the stopwords file?

Comment: I've never heard of using the Schema Browser to determine stopwords. Most people I've talked to create the file by evaluating their data and what they need it to do for them. Looking at my own Schema Browser, I could see *possibly* doing it, but if I created my stopwords file based on what I saw on the SB, I'd be removing a lot of great content. I do think you might have a tokenizing issue, however, since on my SB I get tokens like pin, port, etc. You really need to spend some time on the Analysis page to see what your analyzer is doing.

Comment: @TMBT Well, I don't really know what I would be looking for in the Analysis page to be honest. I have just looked at the delta import logs, and it seems like it is not processing the documents for some reason. I've included the log about in the UPDATE. Any idea what would be causing this?

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Analysis+Screen, if you haven't seen this already. For the deltas, you should use `${dih.last_index_time}` in your `deltaQuery`.